# Como seleccionar la informacion de una tabla en especifico usando SQLALCHEMY en FLASK?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

estoy usando Flask y SQLALCHEMY
En mi base de datos tengo las 3 tablas con los siguientes nombres:

`2020/20/03`
`2020/21/03`
`2020/22/03`

Las estructuras de las tablas son iguales, es decir que tienen las mismas columnas, entonces como puedo seleccionar el contenido de una tabla en especifico usando comandos de SQLALCHEMY?

Aca les dejo la estructura de mi clase

```
class diario(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    temp = db.Column(db.String(80))
    hum = db.Column(db.String(120))
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano muchas gracias!.

Comment: es decir para cada día estas creando una tabla nueva?

Comment: Si, así es, estoy creando una tabla por día